# Same tag name from different location leads to problems

Tags: mercurial, tags, fabric

I'm using Mercurial and Fabric to deploy my site. I'd never used Fabric before so I copied an example fab file online and then changed the vars to match my own site.

Here are the lines of code:

```
def prod():
    env.hosts                     = ['kevinburke.webfactional.com']
    env.user                      = 'kevinburke'

def deploy():
    require('hosts'                    , provided_by=[prod])

    local ("hg tag --local --force production")
    local ("hg push --remotecmd /home/kburke/bin/hg")  # this works fine
    run ("cd /my/web/directory; hg update -C production")
```

and this is invoked from the command line as

```
fab prod deploy
```

When I was the only person deploying the site, this worked with no problems. But recently I added two committers who are running the same fabfile, and when they try deploying the site, the remote version of the site doesn't update to the latest version - it updates only to the latest version that **I** tagged as production, not the one that they tagged.

I expect that it would use their "production" tag to update the file. Why does this happen? How can I get the program to behave as I expect in the future?

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't publish local tags. This means that either your first step is already performed in the `/my/web/directory` repo, or that there is already a `production` called revision there (you can check with `hg tags`, `hg branches` and `hg bookmarks`).

You have several ways to fix your workflow (in order of preference):

- use common-prefixed tags to distinguish between different production revisions, like `production-23` or `production-42`, which you can parse on the production box.
- Create a `production` branch, where every revision to deliver is merged into this branch. I recommend this one if you already have experience with branches.
- Use the [bookmark](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/BookmarksExtension) extension, and create a `production` bookmark to keep track of your deployed version. This looks like the solution you currently want to establish. When you want to use bookmarks, you need to enable them both on the server and all clients, and use `hg push -B production` to push the current state of your bookmark to the server. One disadvantage of this process is that you will never see if anyone had pushed an other bookmark to the server, since the transmission of the bookmark silently rewrites the bookmark on the server.
- Use regular tags to keep track of the production version. On the one hand it seems to be wrong to use tags for this kind of tracking, since tags are meant to be static. On the other hand you would have a track about which revisions where alive on some point in time. But the first solution does the tracking job much better.

Answer (score 1):

May be basic, but did you see that it did indeed do anything? It might be that nothing happened and the deployed was your "production" tag when you had run it.

Since `hg tag --local` means the tag is only for your local repo and is not versioned, I cannot think of any other reason. Others won't even be able to know about the tag.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. If the tag was doing nothing, then what was happening when I wrote "hg update -C production" on the server? When the other committers ran the fab file, it updated to the latest version that I uploaded to the server, not to the tip. Why would it do that?

Comment: As in are people using their own paths for `/home/kburke/bin/hg` and `/my/web/directory` or same fab file means literally the same fab file?

Comment: They're using literally the same fab file (different people deploying to the same site from their local machines). Everything in the repo is in the same place.

Comment: Can you update your question with the entire task and the commandline used to invoke it?

Comment: OK, I've updated the question. All three of use use exactly the same file and same command on our own laptops. There's only one web server.

Comment: If you are using `hg update -C production` how will the remote repo know about the tagged local repo?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's why I asked the question. It was working fine (roughly 3 months, 100 operations) before multiple people began trying to run the same operation

Comment: Can  you tell what you have for `env.hosts`?